# How to access more than 2 DOM elements "The AngularJS way"?

Tags: html, angularjs, dom, directive

I'm starting to learn angularJS better, and I've noticed that AngularJS tries to make strong emphasis on separating the view from the controller and encapsulation. One example of this is people telling me DOM manipulation should go in directives. I kinda got the hang of it now, and how using link functions that inject the current element allow for great behavior functionality, but this doesn't explain a problem I always encounter.

Example:
I have a sidebar I want to open by clicking a button. There is no way to do this in button's directive link function without using a hard-coded javascript/jquery selector to grab the sidebar, something I've seen very frowned upon in angularJS (hard-coding dom selectors) since it breaks separation of concerns. I guess one way of getting around this is making each element I wish to manipulate an attribute directive and on it's link function, saving a reference it's element property into a dom-factory so that whenever a directive needs to access an element other than itself, it can call the dom-factory which returns the element, even if it knows nothing where it came from. But is this the "Angular way"?

I say this because in my current project I'm using hard-coded selectors which are already a pain to mantain because I'm constantly changing my css. There must be a better way to access multiple DOM elements. Any ideas?

Comment: can usually do this sort of thing using scope variables (or a service) and `ng-class` or `ng-show` etc. Both allow use of ng-animate. Good practice to think about how to use data binding of  built in directives before adding more of your own dom manipulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to approach this.

One approach, is to create a create a `sidebar` directive that responds to "well-defined" broadcasted messages to open/close the sidebar.

```
.directive("sidebar", function(){
  return {
    templateUrl: "sidebar.template.html",
    link: function(scope, element){
      scope.$root.$on("openSidebar", function(){
         // whatever you do to actually show the sidebar DOM content
         // e.x. element.show();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Then, a button could invoke a function in some controller to open a sidebar:

```
$scope.openSidebar = function(){
   $scope.$root.$emit("openSidebar");
}
```

Another approach is to use a `$sidebar` service - this is somewhat similar to how `$modal` works in angularui-bootstrap, but could be more simplified.

Comment: Is scope.$root the same as $rootScope? And how could I implement your $scope.$root.$emit using a "controller as" syntax in controllers where I bind properties to the "this" object over the $scope variable?

Comment: Yes, `scope.$root` is a reference for `$rootScope`. From the View (controllerAs or not) you should be able to do `ng-click="$root.$emit('openSidebar')"`

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have a directive on a button and the element you need is outside the directive, you could pass the class of the element you need to toggle as an attribute

```
<button my-directive data-toggle-class="sidebar">open</button>
```

Then in your directive

```
App.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            angular.element('.' + attrs.toggleClass).toggleClass('active');
        }
    };
}
```

You won't always have the link element argument match up with what you need to manipulate unfortunately.  There are many "angular ways" to solve this though.

You could even do something like:

```
<div ng-init="isOpen = false" class="sidebar" ng-class="{'active': isOpen}" ng-click="isOpen = !isOpen">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Mmhh..that's pretty good, I didn't think of that but somehow I feel like adding an attribute would just move the work of updating duplicate class/id selectors from the javascript into the HTML. It's still much better than hard-coding it into the directive though. I'll keep it in mind and mark as best answer if nothing better gets answered. Also, thanks for the ng-class solution, I completely forgot about that, and you are right in it being a pretty angular-way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

The best way for directive to communicate with each other is through events. It also keeps with the separation of concerns. Your button could `$broadcast` on the `$rootScope` so that all scopes hear it. You would emit and event such as `sidebar.open`. Then the sidebar directive would listen for that event and act upon it.

Comment: Oh wow, I never tought of that, maybe because I have yet t ouse the $broadcast service. As a quick question, I tought one should never use the $rootScope, and even less in a directive, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Most of the rational behind not using $rootScope is to not be placing all of your business values there to avoid scope soup. Just using the existing scope and `$broadcast` and `$emit` may not get the event to the directive, as sibling directive would miss the event.

Comment: It is kind of the same argument that you should never use `$element` in a controller. I follow the mantra that you should not do DOM manipulation in a controller so you can test the controller more easily. However I have used `$element` in a controller to access properties on the element the controller is defined on and make the code more sane instead of doing it in the link of a directive and pushing new values into the controller.